# Arduino sketch does not work, the pins do not output anything

Tags: c, arduino, led, infrared, pins

I have an Arduino Uno, and I'm trying to control my s107g rc helicopter with it. This code was available for download along with a few Youtube videos showing tests of it. So when I tried it with the IR led it didn't work.

I tested it with normal leds, I checked pins 8 and 13 with my multimeter (the pins being used) but the pins do not output anything. I believe I am using the code right. I open the serial console and it shows info as it should when I type a command and the lights on the Arduino (TX and RX) flash and light L stays on.

The code will be below. I'm pretty sure I'm using it right so if you can help me it would be well appreciated. I'm new to this. Also, it says to connect the IR led to pin 8. I'm not sure if I'm doing that right. (I connected the positive side to pin 8 and negative to ground)

LINK TO SITE: [S107G Helicopter Control via Arduino](http://abarry.org/s107g-helicopter-control-via-arduino/)

[CODE](http://pastebin.com/QXWVPNh8)

Comment: As a side note, this looks like a really cool project

Answer (score 3):

The code seems to be working fine. In my arduino instead of IR, I tried using a normal LED and changed the delays in the `delayMicroseconds()` function to some larger values(so that flashing could be visible to my eyes) and I could see the LED flashing. I could also see the desired outputs on the serial monitor. I am not sure what the problem is. Are some simple codes like just blinking the LEDs working fine with your arduino?